# Retirar tudo após ? no nome do arquivo

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal

Olá!

Estou tentando renomear uma quantidade grande de arquivos no linux, porém não estou conseguindo acertar o comando. O caso é o seguinte:

Tenho diversos arquivos dentro de um diretório e seus subdiretórios que possuem o seguinte formato de nome *nome_do_arquivo.ext?alguma_coisa* e eu preciso renomear todos eles mantendo apenas *nome_do_arquivo.ext*, ou seja, retirar tudo o que estiver após o *?* e inclusive o *?*.

Já tentei tudo quanto é comando que achei na internet, pesquisei a documentação de *rename*, *find*, *mv*, etc, mas não consegui fazer o que preciso.

Listar eu até consigo com *find* e com *ls*, mas na hora de renomear é que não consigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o utilitário `find` para percorrer todos os arquivos da árvore de um determinado diretório recursivamente:

```
find ./xyz -type f
```

Cada arquivo encontrado teria seu nome alterado com o utilitário `cut`:

```
cut -f1 -d"?"
```

E depois renomeados com o utilitário `mv`.

Colocando tudo junto:

```
$ find ./xyz/ -type f -exec bash -c 'f=$(cut -f1 -d"?" <<< {}); mv "{}" "${f}"' \;
```

Exemplo ANTES:

```
$ tree ./xyz/
./xyz/
|-- alpha?k=5&x=3
|-- kwy
|   |-- apples?t=3
|   |-- bananas?q=1
|   `-- oranges?q=7
|-- omega?k=5&x=3
|-- qwerty?k=5&x=3
`-- teste?x=1&y=2

1 directory, 7 files
```

Exemplo DEPOIS:

```
$ tree ./xyz/
./xyz/
|-- alpha
|-- kwy
|   |-- apples
|   |-- bananas
|   `-- oranges
|-- omega
|-- qwerty
`-- teste

1 directory, 7 files
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.
O que você pode fazer é criar um bash e executar dentro da pasta que quer renomear os arquivos, percorrendo os arquivos e cortando a string.

Arquivo bash (rename.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in * ; do 
newName=$(echo $file| cut -d'?' -f 1)
mv -v $file $newName
done
```

Modo de execução:

`./rename.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar substituição de parâmetros no bash.

Se não houver '?' em 'alguma_coisa'. Remova de `$f` o caminho mais curto até encontrar o padrão `?`

```
for f in *; do mv -v "$f" "${f%\?*}" ; done
```

Se não houver '?' em 'nome_do_arquivo.ext'. Remova de `$f` o caminho mais longo até encontrar o padrão `?`

```
for f in *; do mv -v "$f" "${f%%\?*}" ; done
```

Perceba que não estou verificando se `f` é um arquivo. Ele vai fazer a mesma coisa com diretórios e links.